# algebraic de Rham cohomology of toric varieties (reference request)

Tags: characteristic-p, toric-varieties, derham-cohomology, log-geometry

I haven't been able to find anything workable yet, but I'm looking for a reference on the de Rham cohomology of toric varieties, where as many as possible of the following conditions are handled:

- Possibly singular (but still normal) toric varieties
- Relative dR cohomology of a (toric) morphism of toric varieties
- Characteristic $p$
- Calculation described in fan-theoretic terms (polytope is second-best)

For the relative cohomology of a morphism, by far the most important cases are where the morphism is relative dimension 1, or where the base is dimension 1.

In addition to ordinary de Rham, I would also be interested in logarithmic de Rham cohomology.

The singularities and the positive characteristic usually throw a big wrench into de Rham calculations, but I was really hoping that things would be nicer in the toric situation.

I would be really grateful for some references!

Comment: Here are some suggestions: Oda [The algebraic de Rham theorem for toric varieties](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178225918), Blickle [Cartier Isomorphism for Toric Varieties](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869300985697), Ogus "Lectures on Logarithmic Geometry" (there's a section on the de Rham complexes of monoid algebras)

Comment: @MinseonShin Thank you. I had looked through the first and third already, but will continue looking deeper. And the Cartier isomorphism one looks very promising.